# javascript | save textarea value with line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, save

I have a code where it saves multiple textarea values in a text file. However, it does not display the line breaks I indicated after saving it. It only identifies the line breaks w/c are manually put within the textarea. Below is the code. Please help.

```
<script>
    var TestVar = new Array(); 
    var i = 0;
    function save()
    {
        TestVar[i] = document.getElementById("text1").value + "\n" + document.getElementById("text2").value;
        mydoc = document.open();
        mydoc.write(TestVar);
        mydoc.execCommand("saveAs",true,"TicketID.txt");
        mydoc.close();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id=formtest>
        <textarea name="textarea" id="text1"></textarea>
        <textarea name="textarea" id="text2"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="save" onclick="save()">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: what is your server side code that saves this data?

Comment: if you are on PHP, you should consider using "nl2br" PHP function when saving your textbox's data in the table. you can later convert your any "<br />"'s accouring in the table with: str_replace("<br />", "\n", $textboxValue);

Comment: Hi. Not using any server side scripting since it will only save the file locally.

Answer (score 29):

```
text = text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
```

text is value from textarea.

Comment: When I try this '<br />' is printed in the text area. There is no line break.

Answer (score 14):

The problem stems from the fact that line breaks (`\n`) are not the same as HTML `<br />` tags.

Try this:

```
var text = document.forms[0].txt.value;
text = text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
```

**Edit**, try this as the js:

```
var text = document.forms[0].txt.value;

if (text === true) { text = text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />'); } 

var TestVar = new Array(i); 
var i = 0;
function save()
{
TestVar[i] = document.getElementById("text1").value + "/n" + document.getElementById("text2").value;
mydoc = document.open();
mydoc.write(TestVar);
mydoc.execCommand("saveAs",true,"TicketID.txt");
mydoc.close();
}
```

Comment: tried that and it giving me the error below. Webpage error details

Message: 'document.forms.0.txt' is null or not an object
Line: 4
Char: 1
Code: 0

Comment: Webpage error details Message: 'document.forms.0.txt' is null or not an object Line: 4 Char: 1 Code: 0

Comment: Thanks but not sure if I am doing it correctly. Still got the same error message.

Comment: var text = document.forms[0].txt.value;
function replaceText()
{
if (text == true) { text = text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');  } 
}