# make text input autoresize as typing

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

i want to have a text input with autoresize when the user types more then one line.

i tried using html5 `contenteditable` but it's too complicate to get the data. (this solution isn't working for me [Extracting text from a contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455931/extracting-text-from-a-contenteditable-div) and also there is this warning " It is also possible that an update to any browser could break this function if they change how they implement contentEditable.")

i also tried [this plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) but i don't know how to update the textarea content. after typing if i'm checking for `$('textarea').html()` i'm getting empty value.

Edit: basically, the most important thing for me is to get line break if the user press on enter key.

Comment: Do you want to use a textarea or <input type="text">?

Comment: @PraveenSingh i don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own plugin to autoresize a text area.
Try this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.txt').on('keyup', function(event) {
     var textareaElm = event.target;
        if (textareaElm.scrollHeight > textareaElm.clientHeight) {
            textareaElm.style.height = textareaElm.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
 });
})
```

```css
.txt {
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 transition: height 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="txt"></textarea>
```

Here is a jsfiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/t1cg7f20/

This example uses jQuery. Let me know if you need a JS only solution.

Comment: the autoresize is working great. but i'm still not getting line break with val().
the value is:
"1
2
3
4
5"

Comment: @user2587454 you want to get linebreaks in val()?

Answer (score 0):

To access a `<textarea>`s value you'll want to use

```
$('textarea').val()
```

It should also work with your plugin.

Comment: i'm getting an empty value

Comment: I just checked on the plugin website - could you try if `$('textarea').value` works for you?

Comment: Thanks. value is working for me BUT i don't get line break. if the user pressed on 'Enter' i want to see a line break and not just white space.

Comment: The line breaks are there, they are just hidden characters which you have to check yourself if you want to display them in html or so - check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12896554/1856221

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Praveen Singh, i'm using his code to autoresize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.txt').on('keyup', function(event) {
    var textareaElm = event.target;
    if (textareaElm.scrollHeight > textareaElm.clientHeight) {
        textareaElm.style.height = textareaElm.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
});
```

})

```
.txt {
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
transition: height 0.2s linear;
```

}

and `replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />')` to show line break.