# Is .value preventing line breaks in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How do I get line breaks in my template to show in the textarea?**

I am trying to add a line break in each template after the `,` and can't use `</ br>` either I think due to using`.value`.

I tried [JavaScript: How to add line breaks to an HTML textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/javascript-how-to-add-line-breaks-to-an-html-textarea) and [javascript | save textarea value with line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896504/javascript-save-textarea-value-with-line-breaks) as well as a suggestion to use `style="white-space:pre-wrap"`.

```js
var template_Birthday = "Hey <NAME>, This is the Birthday Template.";
var template_NewJob = "Hey <NAME>, This is the New Job Template.";

var content = function() {
  var e = document.getElementById("template");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if (strUser === "template_NewJob") {
    messageBodyTextarea.value = template_NewJob;
  } else if (strUser === "template_Birthday") {
    messageBodyTextarea.value = template_Birthday;
  }
};
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="message" id="messageBodyTextarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle?

Comment: `\n` is the escape code for a newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \n for new line.

```
var template_NewJob = "Hey <NAME>,\nThis is the New Job Template.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you're setting the value of a `textArea`, have you tried an escaped newline character:

```
messageBodyTextarea.value = "Hey <NAME>, \nThis is the Birthday Template.";
```

You only need to use `<br />` if you're writing HTML to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

To add a line break to a `textarea` in HTML:

```
<textarea id="myTextarea">Line 1
Line 2
Line 3</textarea>
```

To add a line break to a `textarea` in JavaScript:

```
var ta = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
ta.value = 'Line1\nLine2\nLine3';
```